# "Noted" in German

Tags: translation, english-to-german

What's the German translation of "noted" in the following context:

> A: Note that if you have a parenthesis outside the Mathjax immediately following a curly brace inside, the curly brace won’t display.
>
> B: Noted.

I was told that "Ich habe es zur Kenntnis genommen" is an equivalent but the problem is it has negative connotation and means I don't care much about what you just said. Is there any equivalent in German which as short and neutral as the English one?

Comment: *Ich habe es zur Kenntnis genommen* muss nicht negativ sein. If you want to say something very short, you can say *OK* :)

Comment: The translation what dict.cc gives are *notiert*, *beachtet* and *vermerkt* but it is unusual to say them alone.

Comment: @Em1: Yes, I said "bemerkt" and received some surprised looks! "Ok" is not what I meant, why should I say it?

Comment: *Bemerkt* is here not correct. You could use *bemerkt* in: *Have you noticed that you did something wrong - Yes, I noticed it (Ich hab's bemerkt)* .. Here it is more about *find out* that something is as it is, so you can say: *Ich habe es zur Kenntnis genommen*, *Ich hab's gesehen*, *Es ist mir auch schon aufgefallen* or if you haven't noticed it before *Das habe ich noch nicht gesehen*, *Das war mir entgangen*. .... to be continued

Comment: If someone tells you something and you have to write down (not necessary on the paper, maybe just into your brain ;p) the important information for yourself, then you would take *vermerken* and *notieren*. Example if you changed the job and your boss tells you how you have to do something, then you say: *Ok, ich hab's notiert/vermerkt* and you mean, that you understand it and will do it like that.

Comment: There's nothing like "okay, noted"? If for example someone says "note that every action has an equal and opposite reaction", I'd say "noted, thank you for the tip".

Comment: So, in that case since there someone tells you what you can see (I think he/she is showing you something on paper or on screen) you could say that you have seen it with the examples given in the other comment. *Ich hab's bemerkt* would be possible, if you did it wrong before and this person shows you how he do it and while he is telling you, you perceived what you did wrong.

Comment: Don't forget that you never translate literally. I interpreted the *noted* as a kind of *yes, that's right, I've seen it* and then you can say OK in German, that implicitly tells that you have noticed it.

Comment: In some context *Verstanden* (comprehended) is also OK (fits if someone tell you how to do it) - again, you see it depends on the whole context.

Comment: I see, but if you ask me they don't mean "noted". It means "got it and I'll be more careful from now on" and so on, but with one word.

Comment: AH, in case of *Thank you for the tip*, *OK* is also acceptable. Maybe *Ahhhh, OK*, while *Ahhh* is this sound that we make when we recognize something what we haven't seen before. I don't know any other very short alternative. Maybe *Ja, klar* or *Natürlich*, if you haven't noticed it before. But they are far, far away from *noted*, so if you want to express that, take some of the examples I mentioned above ... or wait for some ideas from the others ;p

Comment: ;p For the case of *I'll be more careful from now on* I already gave some examples, also with *bemerken* ;p You see, it is really important in which context someone explain you that fact.

Comment: how about "alles klar!" or in case the news were unexpected : "Achsoooo alles klar! :)... seriously, I don't think we really have a noted that is casual and short enough.

Comment: Since all answer responds somehow to the *negative connotation* but no one really says the most important point, I want to add as a side note: In spoken language nearly all of the possible answers can be stressed in such a way, that they get a negative connotation, but no one of them is negative by its definition!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- A: (Bitte) beachte ...
- B: Anything affirmative (in addition to those answers already mentioned by the previous posters):

  - (affirmative grunt) non-verbal communication is a surprisingly frequent and interlingual thing...
  - (coll) Jep (or local/sociocultural variants...)
  - (coll) Mach' ich.
  - Ja.
  - Ja, danke.
  - Ja, danke für den Hinweis.
- B: if you wouldn't have noticed without the hint:

  - Oh, danke.

Answer (score 7):

In a context where we also want to say that we don't really care about the previous note given, or we want to express that we already know it we can hear a short

> "Schon klar."

Adding some variants with a more positive connotation that were not yet mentioned:

> - Wird gemacht
> - In Ordnung
> - Ist notiert

Answer (score 6):

I wouldn't say that "ich habe es zur Kenntnis genommen" has a negative connotation but it's a bit long. You can always say

> Alles klar.

It's concise and neutral or slightly positive.

As some comments already alluded to there is also

> Ok.
>
> Verstanden. / Verstehe.

and probably a lot more.

Answer (score 1):

The best translations are:

> Ok.
>   Ok, verstanden.

This is possible, too, but is not so often used in this case:

> Verstanden.

The following are possible, too, but they all have a touch of "I did hear you, but I don't care":

> Ja, klar.
>   Schon klar.
>   Zur Kenntnis genommen.